# Как подключить скрипт python к uipath?

Tags: python

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу код на python привязать к uipath который вычисляет день первого и последнего дня предыдущего месяца.

```
import datetime

def get_previous_month_range(date):

    # Вычисляем первый день текущего месяца
    first_day_of_month = datetime.date(date.year, date.month, 1)

    # Вычисляем первый день предыдущего месяца
    last_month = date.month - 1 if date.month > 1 else 12
    last_month_year = date.year if date.month > 1 else date.year - 1
    first_day_of_last_month = datetime.date(last_month_year, last_month, 1)

    # Вычисляем последний день предыдущего месяца
    last_day_of_last_month = first_day_of_month - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    # Получаем только день первого и последнего дня предыдущего месяца
    first_day = first_day_of_last_month.day
    last_day = last_day_of_last_month.day

    return first_day, last_day
```

Пытаюсь привязать его к uipath, но безуспешно:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто-нибудь сможет объяснить по шагам как это сделать, используя данный код

Comment: "не могу" что??